# Getting error connection failure, transport failure reason: TLS error: 268435581:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: openssl, istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar, istio-operator

We have two istio installed in k8s cluster one is 1.8.6 and 1.14.1.
we have injected 1.8.6 istio in namespace-1 and 1.14.1 istio in namespace-2
Running some workloads on both namespace

when i try to make curl request from one pod(namespace-1) to another pod(namespace-2) getting error
"upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: TLS error: 268435581:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED"

Expectation:- It should hit the API properly.

P.S- It might be issues with the istio version hitting from 1.8 version to 1.14 version

Comment: checkhttps://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/security/ssl